# Laravel loop based on inner values

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `competition` model (the competition is essentially a large form to fill in), that `hasMany` `groups` (groups of fields), which `hasMany` `fields`. When a user fills in a form, I create one `entry` record which `hasMany` field submissions (called elements). So, one entry might look like the following:

```
id    form_id
-------------
2     5
```

The the field submissions (elements) table may look like the following:

```
id    entry_id    field_id   value
----------------------------------
1     2           2          Dave
2     2           3          30
```

So if I run:

```
$entry = Entry::with('elements.field.group')->find($id);
```

I get something like this:

```
{
  "id": 16,
  "competition_id": 1,
  "elements": [
    {
      "id": 8,
      "field_id": 1,
      "entry_id": 16,
      "content": "F",
      "field": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "gender",
        "label": "Gender",
        "type": "radio",
        "group_id": 1,
        "group": {
          "id": 1,
          "order": 1,
          "competition_id": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "field_id": 2,
      "entry_id": 16,
      "content": "fds",
      "field": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name",
        "label": "Your name",
        "type": "text",
        "group_id": 1,
        "group": {
          "id": 1,
          "order": 1,
          "competition_id": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To display these, I'd like to ideally do a `@foreach($groups as $group)`, but the groups only exist in `element->field->group`. How can I go about reorganising the array to allow for this? Is there a way to rearrange the array from the inside out? Or is there a way of sorting the data as I grab it from Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
$groups = Group::with('fields.element.entry')->whereHas('field.element.entry', function($q) use ($id){
    $q->where('entries.id', $id);
})->get();
```